# selenium webdriver later than 2.29.1 not working in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone knows why later version of selenium not working in maven project in eclipse? I have the below code in pom.xml of my maven project and it works fine

```
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.29.1</version>
  </dependency>  
 </dependencies>
```

but if I change the version e.g. 2.29.1 to 2.53 or 3.something , my project doesn't run and gives the ff.error
[image]

Comment: Have you updated your maven project in Eclipse after changeing the pom.xml?

Comment: yes! but still get error after running the project and if revert to 2.9.1 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Right click on the project, go to Maven > Enable Work Space Resolution.

this should start downloading the dependencies and build the project.